# How are [environment] and $env different in powershell?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

On Windows Threshold beta, I can run:

```
$env:username
```

And see the username. I can also run:

```
[environment]::username
```

And see the username.

However while I can run

```
$env:computername
```

To see the hostname, trying to run:

```
[environment]::computername
```

does not show any results.

[image]

**Why doesn't `[environment]::computername` work? What's the difference between `$env` and [environment]?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using

```
[environment]::machinename
```

`$env` is directly  bound to enviroment variable

`[environment]` is a [.net class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.environment(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: So are there two environments? A traditional shell environment, with its own keys and values, and a separate .net environment?

Comment: @mikemaccana The .net class also retrieve value from environmet variable but as a class had methods and properties. Example: ` [environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("computername")` reads the enironment variale but `[environment]::machinename` read the netbios name directly.

Comment: Thanks @CB. Is there ultimately one data store in total or two?

Comment: @mikemaccana I think more then one. If you set `$env:computername = "Jack"` and try read again with $env  and with .net class you have different results.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `[environment]::computername` you are in fact using .NET code in Powershell. So reading the documentation for the [Environment Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reveals that you should use `[environment]::machinename` instead.

`$env` is a shortcut for the environment [PSDrive](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/06/learn-how-to-use-the-powershell-env-ps-drive.aspx).

I don't know why Microsoft uses two different names here.

BTW: There are a lot more ways to get the computername, you could also e.g. use wmi: `Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name`

Comment: another way is just using `hostname.exe` ;)